# Why did I get this [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 1, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]?

Tags: python, algorithm, language-agnostic, math, number-theory

Through much trial and error I found the following lines of python code,

```
for N in range(2**1,2**3):
    print [(2**n % (3*2**(2*N - n))) % (2**N-1) for n in range(2*N+1)]
```

which produce the following output,

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 1, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 1, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 1, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

i.e. powers of 2 up to `2**(N-1)`, 1, and the powers of two reversed. This is exactly what I need for my problem (fft and wavelet related). However, I'm not quite sure *why* it works? The final modulo operation I understand, it provides the 1 in the middle of the series. The factor 3 in the first modulo operation is giving me headaches. Can anyone offer an explanation? Specifically, what is the relationship between my base, 2, and the factor, 3?

Comment: When I run the program, the output is different that what you have listed.

Comment: Not an answer, but, since Python values clarity, why not just use `[2**n for n in range(N)] + [1] + [2**n for n in range(N-1, -1, -1)])`?

Comment: `[0, 0, 0]` cannot be the first result, because the first `N` is 2, which makes the argument of `range()` in the second line `2*2+1 = 5`. Therefore, the first list should have 5 elements.

Comment: [0, 0, 0] has been removed---remnant of earlier code.

Comment: Nope. output still doesn't match what you have as the source code. The range for N is 2-16 so there should be 14 values.

Comment: @typo.pl: The output got truncated. Changed the range from 2**1 to 2**3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, as others have said, there are much simpler implementations possible, and you should probably use these.

But to answer your question, here's why you get this result:

**When n<N:**

2<sup>n</sup> % (3*2<sup>2N-n</sup>) = 2<sup>n</sup>, because 2<sup>n</sup> < 3*2<sup>2N-n</sup>. Then 2<sup>n</sup> % (2<sup>N</sup>-1) = 2<sup>n</sup>, giving the expected result.

**When n=N**:

2<sup>N</sup> % (3*2<sup>2N-N</sup>) = 2<sup>N</sup>, and 2<sup>N</sup> % (2<sup>N</sup>-1) = 1.

**When N<n<=2N:**

Let n = 2N - k. Then:

2<sup>n</sup> % (3*2<sup>2N-n</sup>) = 2<sup>2N-k</sup> % (3*2<sup>k</sup>) = 2<sup>k</sup>*(2<sup>2N-2k</sup> % 3) = 2<sup>k</sup> * (4<sup>N-k</sup> % 3)

Any power of 4 is equal to 1 modulo 3 (because 4=1 (mod 3), so 4<sup>m</sup>=1<sup>m</sup>=1 (mod 3) as well). So the final result is 2<sup>k</sup> = 2<sup>2N-n</sup>, as expected.

**Using other numbers:**

If you use the base *a* instead of 2, and the number *b* instead of 3, the last part would give you:

a<sup>k</sup> * ((a<sup>2</sup>)<sup>N-k</sup> % b)

So you'd need to choose b to be any factor of a<sup>2</sup>-1, which will ensure that ((a<sup>2</sup>)<sup>N-k</sup> % b) = 1 for any k.

Comment: Myself and a colleague went through your reasoning and you're right. Thank you for a very clear and precise answer.

Answer (score 6):

While I love clever solutions as much as the next geek, why don't you use a simple solution if you're having trouble understanding your own code? It'll be much easier to maintain and it's not really slower:

```
def fft_func(ex):
    if ex == 0:
        return [0, 0, 0]
    else:
        return [2**n for n in range(0, ex+1)] + [1] + [2**n for n in range(ex, -1, -1)]
```

Comment: Initially, I was not going to tag this as a python question. Yes, I agree, this solution is the python way---if you are solely concerned with programming. Amongst other languages, I use python to play around with mathematical expressions to see how they behave. My interest remains with the particular expression, because next to me is pen and paper on which a proof needs to appear, of which said expression might form part.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to produce that list:

```
for N in range(2**1,2**3):
    print [2**((N-abs(N-k))%N) for k in range(2*N+1)]
```

Comment: @lafrasu: Yes, but i wrote that (function `f(k) = (N-abs(N-k))%N`) with geometricall imagination.